# Can't build native Android module using STL

Tags: stl, android-ndk

Error is " 'vector' is not a member of 'std' ".
What am I doing wrong?

**Update**: after commenting out the code I finally got the "vector: no such file or directory" error. So, it did NOT find STL includes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have Application.mk and declare which stl you will use

> APP_STL := stlport_shared

Comment: Thank you, that helped. I just had to create Application.mk with APP_STL declared.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you've failed to include vector header properly. Check if there include directive in your implementation file, and there is no vector file in your projects directories.

**Update 1:**

Stlport can be configured to use its own namespace stlport, or not ot use namespace at all. I don't think that this is the case in properly configured Android environment, but examine this possibility too.

Comment: No luck. "stlport has not been declared". And it isn't declared outside of namespace, too.